# Reindexing option not available in magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, cache, indexing, catalog-price-rules, special-price

I applied some product catalog rules and deleted them but site still shows the discount.

I also clicked on apply filter but nothing happened.

Prior to 2.0, I was able to do it from the admin panel. 2.0 has only two options under System > Index Management

Options are:

1. Update on save
2. Update by schedule

All of my indexes need reindexing, as I can see the message "Reindex Required".

[image]

Comment: May be this blog/module will help you : [Magento 2 reindex from admin UI](https://rohitkundale.wordpress.com/2017/05/08/magento-2-reindex-from-admin-ui/)

Answer (score 4):

In production mode Magento should be reindexed by a cronjob, see the documentation for further explanation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html.

If not in production you can force the index to be reloaded with this Magento command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello You use following command in cmd if you using windows `php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex`
[image]